# Sending mails to multiple recipients using Java Mail API and Mailtrap

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using `mailtrap.io` to test email notification functionality in my application using `Java Mail API`. It is working perfectly fine.

I need to check if an email notification is being delivered to multiple recipients. Not sure how do test it using `mailtrap`. Do i need to signup in `mailtrap` to create another account? Do i need to use that account's credentials also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forwarding emails, which will work as whitelist inside inbox settings. If Mailtrap will found this emails inside mail header, it will forward this email.